# VS2015 shows a project as ignored

Tags: git, cmake, visual-studio-2015, gitignore

I was wondering if anyone else has seen this problem I am having. The VS 2015 GUI shows all of the projects in my solution with a little red circle next to it. If I move the cursor over the project the tool tip says ignored.

[image: Ignored Project]

I haven't been able to find anything in the help on what it means. Any ideas?

It doesn't seem to cause any problems, everything still compiles, just disconcerting.

It's not explained here either:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.140).aspx

Environment:
 - VS 2015 Professional
 - cmake 3.3.1 used to generate the files
 - Windows 7 Enterprise

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: That threw me at first.  I originally thought that icon meant the entire project and all its source files weren't in the repo.  El Wrongo.  It just means the project file isn't covered, which is fine.  Took me a bit to figure out how to rebuild it though.  Can't remember how now either.  :\

Answer (score 15):

This is an icon from your source control.

When I select Git and add a file that should be ignored (like test.log), it has that same icon and a tooltip.

With some magnification, this icon resembles a "Do Not Enter" road sign :)

Comment: So is there something in the vcxproj file that tells VS that the file should be ignored?
Because if there is then this could be a bug in Cmake.

Comment: I don't think it's in the project. Those exclusions are typically listed in .gitignore file.

Answer (score 10):

Solved! Thanks for the help Vlad.

When using cmake I put all of the generated files in a sub-directory called build. So that git doesn't think these files are new files I add /build to the .gitignore file. VS is 'informing' me of this with the ignore icon. That is why the ignore does not have any affect on the build.

Jason

Comment: I get the same, yes it does not seem to be serious but looks terrible.. Why do Visual studio designers choose a no entry sign to represent ignored by git!? No entry means do not open do not go here...